# Hiding a view inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using support.v4.app.Fragment and I'm trying to hide a loading view (ProgressBar) once my network class (using AsyncTask) finishes loading all of the data. I made the ProgressBar static and created a static function inside my fragment that the network class calls onPostExecute.

static function inside Fragment:

```
public static void likesFinishedLoading() {
    loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    gvLikes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

network class calling the static function:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    .........
    if (type.equals("PostFragment")) {
        PostFragment.likesFinishedLoading();
    } else if (type.equals("Post")) {
        Post.likesFinishedLoading();
    }
}
```

The type can either be PostFragment (using Fragment from support library) or Post (normal Fragment). The code is implemented exactly the same in PostFragment and Post. In either case, the static function is executed but the view hiding only occurs in Post (the normal Fragment). Can anyone offer any insight? Thanks.

Comment: Are you declaring the loadingView with the same id in both fragments layouts, Post and PostFragment?

Comment: Both fragments are sharing the same layout.

Comment: Could you show how are you declaring your Post ans PostFragment classes? What do you mean by normal Fragment and using Fragment from support library?

Comment: They're identical. I'm using the support Fragment because I want to  be compatible with viewpager.